# How to map one-to-one relationship with JPA in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, one-to-one, spring-rest

I have read several tutorial about one-to-one relation mapping forexample: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html,
http://websystique.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-unidirectional-with-foreign-key-associations-annotation-example/
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne

I beleive I follow these tutorials, however my relational mapping still not works as expected. I have the following classes:

```
@Entity(name = "lesson")
public class Lesson {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID uid;
    private String start_date_time;
    private String end_date_time;
    private String location;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="uid") //uid is the name of the Id i want to reference to in the subject class
    private Subject subject_uid; // subject_uid is the name of the column in my subject table

    public Lesson(UUID uid, String start_date_time, String end_date_time, String location, Subject subject_uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.start_date_time = start_date_time;
        this.end_date_time = end_date_time;
        this.location = location;
        this.subject_uid = subject_uid;
    }
//getters setters

@Entity(name = "subject")
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID uid;
    private String name;
    private String start_date;
    private String end_date;
    private boolean is_lesson_created;

    public Subject(UUID uid, String name, String start_date, String end_date, boolean is_lesson_created) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.name = name;
        this.start_date = start_date;
        this.end_date = end_date;
        this.is_lesson_created = is_lesson_created;
    }
```

The response what the Spring Data Rest creates on /lessons endpoint looks the following:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "lessons" : [ {
      "start_date_time" : "2017-01-08 08:30:00",
      "end_date_time" : "2017-01-08 10:15:00",
      "location" : "A101                                                                                                ",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:3400/lessons/78038aeb-cdc9-4673-990e-36b8c1105500"
        },
        "lesson" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:3400/lessons/78038aeb-cdc9-4673-990e-36b8c1105500"
        },
        "subject_uid" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:3400/lessons/78038aeb-cdc9-4673-990e-36b8c1105500/subject_uid"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:3400/lessons{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:3400/profile/lessons"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

When I want access the `http://localhost:3400/lessons/78038aeb-cdc9-4673-990e-36b8c1105500/subject_uid`link I get a 404.
Is the UUID type effects my mapping? What should I change to be able to access my student_uid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out the problem, which is something I haven't read anywhere. When a one-to-one join has to be done, JPA provides the default name of the join as the table name underscore id(subject_id). In my case, I have a tablename called "subject" in the database and the PK called simply "uid". So what you have to do is append the table name with the name of the attribute, which to join to:

```
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="subject_uid")//the pattern is: "tablename_joined attribute"
    private Subject subject_uid;
```